# OpenSearch sum nested array elements size

Tags: opensearch, elasticsearch-painless

OpenSearch version 2.3.0

I have a nested parcel elements as part of my index mappings

```
"parcels": {
    "type": "nested",
    "properties": {
        ...                                 
    }
},
```

How can I find the index sum of parcels array size.

To clarify, if I have a three documents index:

- document xxx with two parcels
- document yyy with three parcels
- document zzz with one parcel

The aggregation should return 6

This aggregation:

```
{
"size": 0,
    "aggs": {
        "total_parcels": {
            "sum": {
                "script": {
                    "source": "ctx._source.parcels.length"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

fails to compile:

```
"reason": {
    "type": "script_exception",
    "reason": "compile error",
    "script_stack": [
        "ctx._source.parcels.length",
                    "       ^---- HERE"
    ],
    "script": "ctx._source.parcels.length",
    "lang": "painless",
     "position": {
         "offset": 19,
         "start": 0,
         "end": 26
     },
     "caused_by": {
         "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
         "reason": "cannot resolve symbol [ctx._source.parcels.length]"
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question:

Use `params` instead of `ctx`

Also, make sure the property exists with a `query` clause

```
{
    "query": {
        "nested": {
            "path": "parcels",
            "query": {
                "exists": {
                    "field": "parcels"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
        "total_parcels": {
            "sum": {
                "script": {
                    "source": "params._source.parcels.length"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```